# How do I use the NavigationWindow.Navigate method?

Tags: wpf, navigationwindow

I have a NavigationWindow and a folder called Views. In that folder is a user control called Home.

How do I navigate to that page?

Answer (score 0):

```
myNavigationWindow.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/Home.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```